# Citations: What do I do when the article writer's name is the same as mine?

Tags: citations, personal-name

What should I do to give credit to an author whose first name is the same as mine and last name is not provided anywhere? I don't want it to look like I wrote the article which I am citing in any way, shape, or form, but I also don't want to make a big deal out of that one citation. I am using MLA formatting.

Comment: did you mean to write the last name is the same as yours and the first name is not provided?

Comment: Is your name particularly unusual?  If not, people are used to there being more than one Smith, Durand, or Zhao.

Comment: @henning No, I wrote it correctly. My first name is the same.
@ jakebeal It's kind of in the middle. Generic but not the MOST popular.

Comment: Edit x2 actually now that I look at it, more popular than I thought.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation.  Where did you find an article whose author doesn't have a last name listed?  (I'm assuming it's not someone with only one name.)  I've never seen such a thing.  If it's from an unusual source, such as a collection of pseudonymous essays, then it may be worth commenting on this when you cite it.  If you give a first-name-only citation with no comment, it will look really weird and people may assume it's a mistake.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Yeah, the author just has their last name listed. I think for privacy reasons because it's on a hot topic (this is an argumentative essay). As for where I found it, that would kinda give my name out online which I prefer not to do. For siting, I was a bit worried about that - thanks

Comment: I'm confused, but perhaps you could call the author you're citing "Harry X."  When it's the same last name, I've seen "(no relation)".

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks, I'm all set though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just the first name, cite the work as being authored by a mononymic person.  Author names in text are virtually always (a) full name, (b) initials + last name, or (c) just last name.

The consistent use of a first name only, along with an entry in the works cited whose author has that name and that name alone, will make it clear that you are a different person (especially if you actually do quote yourself and have a *separate* entry, in Last, First format with your works).

If you still feel that there is the possibility for confusion, upon first mention of the author, insert a footnote or parenthetical statement to clarify the distinction.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I don't have any of my own "quotes" that I put in this essay, but I did use my full name at the top for demonstration purposes.